# Value Error during merging two data frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, merge

I have 2 data frames:

```
visit_final.iloc[0:10]
Out[48]: 
         mac_address  no. of visit during peak hour
0  00:02:1a:11:b0:b9                              1
1  00:02:71:d6:04:84                              1
2  00:05:33:34:2f:f2                              1
3  00:08:22:04:c4:fb                              1
4  00:08:22:06:7b:41                              1
5  00:08:22:07:48:15                              1
6  00:08:22:08:a8:54                              1
7  00:08:22:0e:0a:fc                              1
8  00:08:22:10:4f:d0                              1
```

and

```
iphone_final.iloc[0:10]
Out[47]: 
         mac_address  no. of high iphone co_visit
0  00:02:1a:11:b0:b9                            1
1  00:02:71:d6:04:84                            1
2  00:05:33:34:2f:f2                            1
3  00:08:22:04:c4:fb                            1
4  00:08:22:06:7b:41                            1
5  00:08:22:07:48:15                            1
6  00:08:22:08:a8:54                            1
7  00:08:22:0e:0a:fc                            1
8  00:08:22:10:4f:d0                            1
9  00:08:22:14:e1:fb                            1
```

I am trying to merge these 2 by using

```
final = pd.merge('visit_final','iphone_final', how = 'outer', on =['mac_address'])
```

but this produces an error

```
type {0}'.format(type(left)))

ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <type 'str'>`
```

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code: you are trying to merge to objects of type string...

```
final = pd.merge("a","b", how = 'outer', on =['mac'])
```

But you should rather:

```
final = pd.merge(a, b, how = 'outer', on =['mac'])
```

So just remove the quotation marks around the variables.